# Get last modified values for each records from two tables joins?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `accounts` and `calls`. `Account` table contain the Account details and `call` table contain the call details like `date_modified` and others with account id in `parent_id` column.

There are lots of the records and I need a query which fetch all the accounts with their last call details (Most recent call).

I have tried this but not able to get the result.

```
SELECT accounts.id, accounts.name, calls.name subject 
FROM accounts 
INNER JOIN calls ON accounts.id = calls.parent_id 
WHERE accounts.id=(
   SELECT c.parent_id 
   FROM calls c 
   WHERE c.parent_id = calls.parent_id 
   ORDER BY c.date_modified DESC LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `WHERE accounts.id IN` instead of `=`?

Comment: is there a primary key on the calls table ? - if so is it an auto increment field

Comment: Yes there is an primary field but its type is base64 so that I am not using it for getting max value. @IanKenney..

Comment: Do you get any records returned or the wrong results?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this query and let me know the result:

```
SELECT accounts.id, accounts.name, calls.name subject 
FROM accounts 
INNER JOIN calls ON accounts.id = calls.parent_id 
WHERE calls.date = (
   SELECT max(c.date)
   FROM calls c 
   WHERE c.parent_id = calls.parent_id)
```

Comment: Yes, Its working but it give me only 36 records but as per my other custom query that gives approximate 4000 records. Some of the calls.date should be same for same account. Can you please modified it again so that it give me right results.@mahmoud

Comment: @GauravSharna Unfortunately I dont understand you. please give us sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1):

Try this query: it should work.

```
SELECT * FROM Accounts A
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        c.parent_id
        ,c.name
        ,c.date_modified
    FROM calls C
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            parent_id
            ,MAX(date_modified) call_date
        FROM calls 
        GROUP BY parent_id
    ) CC ON CC.parent_id = c.parent_id AND CC.call_date = c.date_modified

) CCC ON CCC.parent_id = A.id
```